# Thin Film Interference - longest wavelength of the light in water that is transmitted most easily

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, waves, visible-light, interference

The problem:

> A scientist notices that an oil slick floating on water when viewed
> from above has many different colors reflecting off the surface,
> making it  look rainbow-like. She aims a spectrometer at a particular
> spot and measures the wavelength to be 750 nm (in air). The index of
> refraction of water is 1.33. Now assume that the oil had a thickness
> of 200 nm and an index of refraction of 1.5. A diver swimming
> underneath the oil slick is looking at the same spot as the scientist
> with the spectrometer. What is the longest wavelength of the light in
> water that is transmitted most easily to the diver?

My attempt:

I tried to find the wavelength at which the scientist would see constructive interference. I know that is not what the problem asks but I figured I could find the wavelength from that. The top reflected ray experiences phase shift while the bottom reflected ray does not, hence the equation to satisfy constructive interference is:

[image]

So I did that, setting m = 0 and then m = 1, and then used the relationship $\lambda_{oil}n_{oil}=\lambda_{water}n_{water}$ to calculate wavelength in water. However, in both my cases of m = 1 and m = 0, I calculated the wavelength of water to be outside of the range of the visible spectrum (900 and 266 nm).
[image]

The correct answer for the wavelength of light in water 450 nm and I discovered that the only way to get this is if I set m = 0.5, but m can only be an integer. The other alternative is that the scientist actually sees a dark spot while the diver looking up sees a bright spot. Then I can use the destructive interference equation ($2t=m\lambda_{oil}$). This is the only case where $\lambda_{oil}$ will have a coefficient of 1, giving 400 nm for the wavelength in the oil, and thus 450 for wavelength in water. So what is the case here?

Comment: Hello! It is [preferable](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/) to type out screenshots or images of text; for formulae, one can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Comment: Think a little bit more about whether you want _constructive_ or _destructive_ interference here.

Answer (score 1):

The light is reflected best when constructive interference occurs.

Conversely, the light is *transmitted* best when *destructive* interference occurs.

That's why you're getting $m=0.5$: you should actually be solving for when destructive interference occurs.

Comment: That makes sense. You said light is transmitted best when destructive interference occurs. Do you know a source where I can read more about this?

Comment: @BlueMagic1923 In essence, it's due to conservation of energy. Constructive interference means that more light is reflected. If more light is reflected, then less light must be transmitted. The same reasoning works for destructive interference - if less light is reflected, more of it must be transmitted.